# Is Vidui before a Talmid Chacham permitted? (based on Breslov/Likutei Mohoran)

Tags: halacha, chasidut-hasidism, viduy-confession, breslov

In [Likutei Mohoran Torah 4](https://www.sefaria.org/Likutei_Moharan.4.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), it explains about the process of confession before a Talmid Chacham and how that it a significant process. How does that fit in with what is recorded in the Talmud/Rambam that acknowledging one's sins against Hashem to others is forbidden/detestable?

Thanks

**Berachos 34b**

> ואמר רב כהנא חציף עלי מאן דמפרש חטאיה שנאמר (תהלים לב, א) אשרי נשוי פשע כסוי חטאה

**Rambam H' Teshuva 2:5**

> וְשֶׁבַח גָּדוֹל לַשָּׁב שֶׁיִּתְוַדֶּה בָּרַבִּים וְיוֹדִיעַ פְּשָׁעָיו לָהֶם וּמְגַלֶּה עֲבֵרוֹת שֶׁבֵּינוֹ לְבֵין חֲבֵרוֹ לַאֲחֵרִים וְאוֹמֵר לָהֶם אָמְנָם חָטָאתִי לִפְלוֹנִי וְעָשִׂיתִי לוֹ כָּךְ וְכָךְ וַהֲרֵינִי הַיּוֹם שָׁב וּמִתְנַחֵם. וְכָל הַמִּתְגָּאֶה וְאֵינוֹ מוֹדִיעַ אֶלָּא מְכַסֶּה פְּשָׁעָיו אֵין תְּשׁוּבָתוֹ גְּמוּרָה שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (משלי כח יג) "מְכַסֶּה פְשָׁעָיו לֹא יַצְלִיחַ". בַּמֶּה דְּבָרִים אֲמוּרִים בַּעֲבֵרוֹת שֶׁבֵּין אָדָם לַחֲבֵרוֹ **אֲבָל בַּעֲבֵרוֹת שֶׁבֵּין אָדָם לַמָּקוֹם אֵינוֹ צָרִיךְ לְפַרְסֵם עַצְמוֹ וְעַזּוּת פָּנִים הִיא לוֹ אִם גִּלָּם. אֶלָּא שָׁב לִפְנֵי הָאֵל בָּרוּךְ הוּא וּפוֹרֵט חֲטָאָיו לְפָנָיו וּמִתְוַדֶּה עֲלֵיהֶם לִפְנֵי רַבִּים סְתָם. וְטוֹבָה הִיא לוֹ שֶׁלֹּא נִתְגַּלָּה עֲוֹנוֹ שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (תהילים לב א) "אַשְׁרֵי נְשׂוּי פֶּשַׁע כְּסוּי חֲטָאָה**":

Comment: It could be that although making ones sins before God known to the public is bad, admitting them to one's friend in confidence is acceptable, and confessing them to a _Talmid Chakham_ is meritorious.

Comment: A similar thought is found in Noam Elimelech's [Tzetel Katan](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%9D_%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9A/%D7%94%D7%A6%D7%A2%D7%98%D7%99%D7%9C_%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%9F), note 13.

Comment: [Mohorosh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliezer_Shlomo_Schick) is said to have said in [a letter](http://www.breslevcity.co.il/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%A1%D7%9C%D7%91_4218), that one must confess only to God, and that if he feels that he has to tell someone else (to get advise for what to do in his situation), then he should only do so to a great _Tzadiq_ and _Talmid Chakham_. ...

Comment: ... In [another letter](http://www.breslevcity.co.il/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%A1%D7%9C%D7%91_3784) he said that one is not to tell his sins to others (like in a support group), but to God alone, and that one may confess to a _Talmid Chakham_, only because the latter nullifies himself before God.

Comment: @ezra Note #13 seems to be talking about one's "challenges", not necessarily sins that might have been done in a moment of "weakness." Discussing one's challenge with their teacher/mentor makes total sense (getting advice etc.), and according to the Noam Elimelech ztzl has esoteric importance as well, sharing one's failings before Hashem might be a different situation.

Comment: @Fei23 - That's why I said it was a similar thought, not the exact same thing discussed in Likutei Moharan. It does say that one should talk with his mentor about all the sinful _thoughts_ that arise in one's mind, and thoughts are the beginning to physical sin in many cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R' Nachman could have been inclined to the Raavad's opinion that sins committed against God may be publicized so the person experiences humiliation. (See Lechem Mishneh [Teshuvah 2:5](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=90639&rid=397) justifying the opinion of Raavad.)

Possibly more in line with R' Nachman's description of confessing to a rabbi is the instruction of Sefer Hasidim (§21) that that which the Talmud admonishes one who discloses his sins ([Ber. 34b](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%9C%D7%93_%D7%91)) refers to disclosing to the public, however one may tell a righteous, modest person of his sin **so he may receive guidance how to repent**.